# AlarmManager.setRepeating Аттрибуты

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

```
public void setRepeating(@AlarmType int type, long triggerAtMillis,
        long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

Метод, который повторяет какое-то действие в указанная в аттрибуте intervalMillis время. Не могу просто понять зачем нужен triggerAtMillis?

Answer (score 1):

`triggerAtMillis` нужен для того, чтобы указать через сколько `AlarmManager` должен сработать после старта.
Например:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
      SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, 10000, intent)
```

данный `alarmManager` - повторяющийся каждые 10 секунд с первым запуском через 5 секунд от текущего времени